# AngularTS recursive filter on nested array

Tags: angular, typescript, recursion, lambda, filter

I have a problem which requires a function that can recursively traverse a nested array of objects and filter elements out based on whether or not they are present in a list of views.

For example, given a list:

```
[{
    "label": "Heading",
    "items": [{
      "label": "Subheading",
      "items": [{
          "id": "item1_priv",
          "label": "item1"
        },
        {
          "id": "item_priv2",
          "label": "item2"
        },
        {
          "label": "Subheading",
          "items": [{
            "id": "item_priv3",
            "label": "item3"
          }]
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "label": "Heading2",
    "items": [{
      "label": "Subheading",
      "items": [{
          "id": "item_priv4",
          "label": "item4"
        },
        {
          "id": "item_priv5",
          "label": "item5"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
]
```

and a list of views:

```
canView = ['item1','item2','item4','item5']
```

The function needs to filter out `item3` in the list as it is not present in `canView`.

I have already made a function that does this:

```
public filterView(list: any[]): any {

  for (const item of list) {
    if (item.items) {
      item.items = this.filterView(item.items);
    } else {
      list = ((list.filter((i: any) => this.hasView(i.id))));
    }
  }

  return list;
}
```

However, my question is: Is it possible to rewrite this function as a lambda using list.filter()? I'm new to Angular to and Typescript so I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around using filter (or nested filters) in order to traverse the list based on whether not it possesses items.

my assumption would be a function along the lines of

```
list.filter(item => return(item.items && this.hasView(item.items.id)))
```

but this doesn't seem to work on a list with dynamic depth. Any advice would be appreciated as other solutions to similar problems I've seen have only had lists with fixed depths.

Comment: What is `hasView` expected to return?

Comment: hasView returns a boolean based on whether or not the id of the item is present in the canView list.

Answer (score 1):

The only change I would suggest is to do the list filtering once rather than inside the loop:

```
public filterView(list: any[]): any {

  for (const item of list) {
    if (item.items) {
      item.items = this.filterView(item.items);
    }
  }

  return list.filter((i: any) => this.hasView(i.id));
}
```

Beyond that, given that `filterView` is doing two different things (filtering the top-level list and mutating the child lists of the descendants), it seems to me that any more concise way of writing it is going to be harder to understand.